# 2d object moving down appears in random places for a frame then goes back normal

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to make this object move down but everytime it goes out of the screen it teleports back up with a different x position but it appears in random places on screen and collides with things. it only has this script and a rb2d and a boxcollider2d. rb2d doesnt have gravity,collision detection continious,interpolate interpolate,sleeping mode never sleep.im new to unity
this is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
    }
    void FixedUpdate(){
        rb.velocity=new Vector2(0f,-5f);
        if (rb.position.y<-5.5f){
            float rndf= Random.Range(-10.14f,10.14f);
            rb.MovePosition(new Vector2(rndf,5.5f));
        }
    }
}
```

[here is a photo of the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZLhy.png)

It was because i moved it and didn't teleport it. It collided with objects on the way

Comment: If I understand this code correctly, once the RigidBody has a certain `y` value it gets a random vector and moves that direction each frame. You should probably implement a way so only _one_ random vector gets generated and the FixedUpdate function doesn't continually do that.

Comment: fixed update only generates the random x value when y value is low enough then it teleports the object  back up and shifts its x value to that random number.That should have no effect on it while its higher than the bottom

Comment: Completely misread the code, my mistake. Do you happen to have a screenshot of the scene by any chance, or a video demonstrating the issue?

Comment: after i hit play button?

Comment: Preferably in the editor.

Comment: i added it to the post

Comment: Seems so basic that it'a even stranger this behavior is happening. Could you record a video of the bug occurring?

Comment: it is really fast it wouldnt be seen on video i just know because it collided with player and caused game over its just going in a straight line it seems but just coliides with player on somewhere else

Comment: Do the collisions happen on the path between its initial location and `MovePosition`?

Comment: Yeah it looks like it but because its random i dont really know where the MovePosition is

Comment: Maybe the issue is caused because it is a move function, maybe just try modify the position instead?

Comment: With transform?Yes thanks because it moves back rhere and doesnt teleport well thank you ill try